# Menu disappears when hovering away from sibling element

Tags: html, css

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I can't find an example that matches my use case.  On hovering over divs, the dropdown menu appears, but as soon as you hover away from the div, the dropdown disappears.  I know that in order to fix this, I need to add a :hover event to the dropdown itself, but I can't figure out a way to do this besides rewriting the whole css rule.

```css
.header .text .nav-link div:hover + .dropdown {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-top: .2rem;
  margin-left: -2rem;
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.header .text .nav-link .dropdown:hover {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-top: .2rem;
  margin-left: -2rem;
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class=nav-link>
  <div class='menu-item'><a href="#">Product</a><img src="images/icon-arrow-light.svg"></div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Marketplace</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Integrations</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *"On hovering over divs, the dropdown menu appears"* - nothing of the sort happens in the snippet you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the `dropdown` to stay open when hovering `product` or the items in the drop down.

You can do this by adding a hover to the `.nav-link` element.

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
  /* This prevents the tiny gap the mouse will hit moving from the link to the dropdown */
  padding-bottom: .2rem;
}

.nav-link:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  /* this should fall within the .nav-link padding */
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: -2rem;
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-link">
  <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">Product</a><img src="images/icon-arrow-light.svg"></div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Marketplace</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Integrations</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Hover over products and your dropdown will show and you can move over the elements.

Comment: I mean that when I add this rule to my stylesheet, the dropdown menu no longer appears on hovering over 'Products'.

Comment: I have no idea what the rest of your code looks like. My answer fixes the code you provided in your question. You may not be able to just add this to your stylesheet, since we only have a very small amount of CSS that you gave us.

Comment: Okay, thank you for helping - I do appreciate it!  I'll look at the rest of my code.  What is the principle at work here that is different from how I was attempting to do it?  Maybe that will help me debug.  Do you think that the problem was the tiny space you mention in the comments?

Comment: The principle is that you need to put the `hover` on the `nav-link` element since it wraps the drop down. So when the drop down is visible, you are still hovering *inside/over* the parent (`nav-link`). You also need to fix your typo, by adding quotes around `nav-link` in your HTML.

Comment: That helps a lot.  Thank you, I really appreciate it.